# How to code a result to a selection from a combobox?

Tags: delphi

I have a TComboBox in Delphi 10.3. I have a Combobox with over 30 items. I need to code a different action for each item of the Combobox. At the moment I'm using if-else statements. As there are 30 different items the if statements are going to be way too long. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: This completely depends on what you are doing. Maybe it's enough to use the `ItemIndex`? Or you could use each item's pointer to store an integer or a pointer. Maybe you should replace the `if`s with a `case`. Maybe you need an integer- or string-keyed dictionary of procedures.

Comment: The items in the Combobox are all string. Case statements require ordinal types so I can't use that. The code I'm using is if Combobox.items[combobox.itemindex] = x then begin y; else if Combobox.items[combobox.itemindex] = a then begin b etc.

Comment: What about `case ComboBox.ItemIndex of 0: DoA; 1: DoB; ...`?

Comment: Can the actions be parameterised or do they have nothing in common? How do you populate the control?

Comment: I've tried that code, it still requires ordinal types. I'm not sure how to parameterise the actions.

Comment: @LiamPeffer Using the `ItemIndex` rather than the actual strings is definitely a good way to go. What is the *actual problem* you are having with doing that? The first item in the list is index 0, so `case 0` will be executed for that.  The 2nd item is index 1, so `case 1` will be executed for that. And so on.  If you [edit] your question to show the actual code you are trying to simplify, maybe someone can give you another solution if you don't want to use the `ItemIndex`.

Comment: "I've tried that code, it still requires ordinal types." Well, `ItemIndex`, `0`, `1`, ... are `Integer`s, and `Integer` is an ordinal type. (The most common one, actually!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **entirely** depends on your situation. It is almost impossible to answer your Q without knowing your precise scenario.

Nevertheless, here are a few ideas. Maybe they are relevant to your situation, maybe they are not.

## Trivial parameterisation by index

In the best case scenario, your 30 actions can be parameterised. For instance, suppose the items of the combo box are

```
Show 1
Show 10
Show 100
Show 1000
...
```

which will display a message box with the given number. In this scenario, you don't need 30 different procedures (here each represented by a simple call to `ShowMessage`):

```
procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
    0:
      ShowMessage('1');
    1:
      ShowMessage('10');
    2:
      ShowMessage('100');
    3:
      ShowMessage('1000');
    // ...
  end;
end;
```

Instead, you should use only one procedure, but with a parameter:

```
procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    ShowMessage(IntPower(10, ComboBox1.ItemIndex).ToString)
end;
```

## Parameterisation by the associated object

If the action cannot be described by the item's index alone, you can use the object pointer associated with each item. Maybe it is enough to use it to store an integer:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Show 51', TObject(51));
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Show 111', TObject(111));
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Show 856', TObject(856));
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Show 1000', TObject(1000));
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    ShowMessage(Integer(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]).ToString);
end;
```

Otherwise, you can let it be a true pointer to some object with any amount of data (integers, strings, ...).

## Unrelated procedures

The examples above all require that the procedures can be parameterised, i.e. replaced by a single procedure with a parameter. If this is not the case, if the procedures are completely unrelated, you need a different approach. But again, which approach is most suitable depends on your precise situation.

Here are a few examples.

### Simple case statement

At design time, set the items to `Play sound`, `Run Notepad`, and `Show Start Menu`.

```
procedure PlaySound;
begin
  MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;

procedure RunNotepad;
begin
  ShellExecute(Form1.Handle, nil, 'notepad', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
end;

procedure ShowStartMenu;
begin
  Form1.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0)
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
    0:
      PlaySound;
    1:
      RunNotepad;
    2:
      ShowStartMenu;
  end;
end;
```

### Storing procedural pointers with the items

```
procedure PlaySound;
begin
  MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;

procedure RunNotepad;
begin
  ShellExecute(Form1.Handle, nil, 'notepad', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
end;

procedure ShowStartMenu;
begin
  Form1.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0)
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Play sound', TObject(@PlaySound));
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('Run notepad', TObject(@RunNotepad));
    ComboBox1.Items.AddObject('ShowStartMenu', TObject(@ShowStartMenu));
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    TProcedure(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[ComboBox1.ItemIndex])();
end;
```

Benefit: no risk of confusing the indices; the actions are "attached" to the items.

### Using a dictionary of commands

Maybe your application has a global set of commands, denoted by English words. Then you might want to use a dictionary to get the procedure associated with a word. This can be used for the combo box as well. At design time, let there be three items: `beep`, `write`, and `start`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    btnNext: TButton;
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCommands: TDictionary<string, TProcedure>;
  public
  end;

procedure PlaySound;
begin
  MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;

procedure RunNotepad;
begin
  ShellExecute(Form1.Handle, nil, 'notepad', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
end;

procedure ShowStartMenu;
begin
  Form1.Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0)
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCommands := TDictionary<string, TProcedure>.Create;
  FCommands.Add('beep', PlaySound);
  FCommands.Add('write', RunNotepad);
  FCommands.Add('start', ShowStartMenu);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCommands.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cmd: TProcedure;
begin
  if
    (ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1)
      and
    FCommands.TryGetValue(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex], Cmd)
  then
    Cmd();
end;
```